# StarCraft2: Breakout vs Ghost of a Chance

Tags: starcraft-2

On my 1st campaign pass I've chosen "Breakout" mission. Now I do that the 2nd time (to have everything done on Brutal) and want to choose "Ghost of a Chance".

Q1:
Remember, that the penultimate mission (I've chosen "Belly of the Beast") require Tosh to participate. If I do "Ghost of a Chance" now (actually, here I will destroy Tosh camp) will Tosh play in penultimate "Belly of the Beast" mission? Or this mission won't be allowed in this pass?

Q2:
What is influence which mission will I chose here on the further campaign?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, what you mention about "Belly of the Beast" is incorrect.  This mission does NOT require Tosh.  Thus, you can feel free to pick Tosh or Nova without affecting any of your later mission choices.  Tosh does not participate in Belly of the Beast even if you do have him.  The mission consists of Raynor, Tychus, Swann, and Stettman only.

That said, there is a strategy that can be found here that relies on using ghosts specifically for the final mission, All-In.  That strategy can be found [here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/All-In#With_Ghosts_and_Upgrades).  Thus, if you want to try that, you'd need to choose Nova.

Other than that, your choice will not affect any future choices in the campaign, except for of course which flavor of cloaked ground unit you prefer most, in the event you actually even make spectres/ghosts at all.  The two abilities that differ are: [Snipe](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Sniper_Round) (ignores armor) for Ghosts and [Ultrasonic Pulse](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Spectre) for Spectres (AoE stun attack).

Comment: +1: I vastly prefer doing Belly of the Beast, and then using the MC turrets on Aces High, but both ghosts and specters are okay for Aces High: With the former its stealth and snipe, and the latter it's stun, and let the tanks clean up. Also, never finished the game with Tosh's people, so it can definitely be done.